# How to add image next to comment text JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, image

I want to be able when I press button "Submit" to add dynamically image. Something like the image below.

[image]

I have researched by my self, but couldn't find any solution. Any kind of help will be helpful :)

[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/MgnKB/7/)

HTML:

```
<textarea id ="comments" cols="30" rows="3"></textarea>
            <input type="submit" value="Submit" id="submit"/> 
            <div id="divComments"></div>
```

JQuery:

```
function addComment(name1) {

        var container = $('#divComments');
        var inputs = container.find('label');
        var id = inputs.length + 1;

        var div = $('<div />', { class: 'CommentStyle' });

        $('<label />', {
            id: 'comment' + id,
            text: name1
        }).appendTo(div);

        div.appendTo(container);   

    }

    $('#submit').click(function () {
        addComment($('#comments').val());
        $('#comments').val("");
    });
```

Comment: Your code has no image, just a div and a label.  What image do you want to add and where?  And the div/label are being added just fine in your demo.

Answer (score 0):

Check That [**`DEMO`**](http://jsfiddle.net/LCA72/)

That Should do your job

```
var img = $('<img>').attr("src", 'http://ssl.gstatic.com/accounts/ui/logo_2x.png').appendTo($('#divComments'));
```

Comment: Nice. How to place the image on a straight horizontal line? Like the image above.

Comment: Just add `display:inline-block` in your `CommentStyle` class [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/LCA72/1/)

Comment: Styling must be added as you want i suppose.